# Transformation of sentences

Tags: sentence, imperatives

1.'How I wish I had a dog!
2. I wish I had a dog.

I came across sentence 2 as the declarative form of sentence 1.

As Sentence 2 has the word 'wish' I was wondering should it be an imperative sentence? If so then what should be the declarative form?

Comment: The imperative version of the sentence would be *Wish for a dog!* Imperatives almost always have *you* as the (unstated but assumed) subject.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Sir.